# How do I change phone number in Active Directory using C#

Tags: c#, active-directory

I have this code where I can change the display name, password, etc. in the Active Directory

```
UserPrincipal userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, userName);
userPrincipal.DisplayName = "Some NAME";
userPrincipal.SetPassword("NEW_PASSWORD");
userPrincipal.Save();
```

I have looked at the properties of userPrincipal and I can not find the phone number property. My question is how do I change the phone number for the User in the code.

Thank You

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Correction (Sorry for all the edits):

Here's what I do......

```
    public static void SetUserInfo(string userName)
    {
        var dsDirectoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://xxxx/DC=xx,DC=xxx", "ADusername", "ADpassword");

        var dsSearch = new DirectorySearcher(dsDirectoryEntry) { Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(SAMAccountName=" + userName + "))" };

        var dsResults = dsSearch.FindOne();
        var myEntry = dsResults.GetDirectoryEntry();
        //myEntry.Properties[property].Value = value;
        myEntry.Properties["telephoneNumber"].Value = "222-222-2222";
        myEntry.CommitChanges();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. I ll check it out.